# How to Change View when OpenFileDialog is Closed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, openfiledialog

This is my first MVVM app, and I am wondering how to switch to another view after the user is done with the `OpenFileDialog`.

The changing view technique currently using is borrowed from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views).

In other word, how to call :

```
private void ExecuteGridViewCommand()
{
    CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel._gridViewModel;
}
```

The problem rises since I couldn't track when the user clicks the Open button of the Dialog since the Dialog is not a XAML control.

```
    private static ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel != value)
            {
                _currentViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody earlier sent an answer (deleted) that was inspiring (thanks) even though it didn't work out of the box, maybe due to instantiating a new instance of ViewModelLocator().

It was something like this:

```
private readonly MainViewModel _mainViewModel = (new ViewModelLocator().Main);
_mainViewModel.ExcuteGridView();
```

After tweaking, now I have this, and it works:

```
ViewModelLocator.Main.ExcuteGridView();
```

In order for this to work though, I had to declare the Main as static inside the ViewModelLocator:

```
 public static MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return _main;
        }
    }
```