# Calling a ViewModel from another during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

For example, 
If a button clicked:

```
// Call second VM from first VM and process values
new SecondViewModel().Values = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
```

Second ViewModel. However, this never works.

```
public string[] Values;

public DatagridViewModel()
{
   ProcessStrings(Values);
}
```

The following works:

```
public string[] Values = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };

public DatagridViewModel()
{
   ProcessStrings(Values);
}
```

It appears to me that things work fine only the first time the ViewModel is compiled. But any other time I try to call it during runtime, it never seems to work. Just wondering what could be wrong.

Comment: Post complete classes if possible please.

Comment: It is not clear what your are asking.

Comment: I suspect you must get the reference of actual `SecondViewModel` instead of creating new one.

Comment: Check for the Address of Value they will be different. try assigning some space to values at the level of construction then you can add some values. and that will be referencing the same location.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, could you please elaborate on what you mean by getting a reference of the actual SecondViewModel. Sounds logical instead of instantiating a new one, but not sure how to do so.

Comment: Where are you create your second VM?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan In order to use the same ViewModel instance, I had to make the SecondViewModel property inside the MainViewModel public (ex: public SecondViewModel secondViewModel { get; set; }). And from the FirstViewModel, I call var vm = ViewModelLocator.MainViewModel.secondViewMOdel. However, the shortcoming of using the same instance is that View binding is never reset to null. So for example, if I process new data and add it to the Grid, the DataGrid still display the old data plus the new

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Values` property hasn't been set yet the way you're calling it; the constructor needs to complete before the setter is called and `Values` hasn't been set yet while in the constructor.  You'd have to pass the values into the constructor, or set `Values` later:

```
var vm = new SecondViewModel();
vm.Values = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
vm.ProcessStrings();
```

Even better, use a property:

```
private string[] values;
public string[] Values
{
    get { return values; }
    set
    {
        if (this.values == value)
            return;

        this.values = value;
        this.ProcessStrings();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this still doesn't work for me. I have a DataGrid where I load and display all processed values. The DataGrid is bound to a List property that is based on those values. However, even though this List is changed during runtime using the technique you described, the DataGrid is always empty, and only display something if I passed the values through the constructor the first time the App is compiled. Maybe this has to do with the technique I used to switch views, found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468544/how-to-change-view-when-openfiledialog-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

If you create VM in button event handler, first is call constructor and after them is assigned array to `Values`. So if you call in constructor `ProcessStrings(Values)`, parameter is `null`.